# SQL And OR statement

Tags: sql, powerbi-desktop

I've got a SQL statement I'm trying to run for Power BI- below is a version of the statement that seems to work:

```sql
     SELECT source_name, lot_key, trx_key, trx_time, route_ndame
     FROM TRX_BASE
     WHERE trxtime >'12/31/2023' 
      AND (op_n IS NOT NULL 
      AND ( route_n = 'CS-161' 
           OR route_n = 'CS2-161' 
           OR route_n = 'DB-357' 
           OR route_n ='DB-437' 
           OR route_n ='SPW-300'))
```

The problem is I found out the "SPW-300" data all has a null for op_n, so I'd like to write a statement for trxtime 12/31, and either has route_n = 'SPW-300' OR has op_n Null AND route_n='CS-161' OR route_n='CS2-161', etc.

I've tried moving the "OR route_n = 'SPW-300" outside the right most parenthesis and that the code just errors out due to trying to run for too long when I do that. Is there a better way to write this?

Answer (score 0):

probably you want something like this:

```
SELECT source_name, lot_key, trx_key, trx_time, route_ndame
FROM TRX_BASE
WHERE
    trxtime > '12/31/2023'
    AND
    (
            (route_n = 'SPW-300')
            OR
            (
                (op_n IS NOT NULL)
                AND
                (route_n IN ('CS-161', 'CS2-161', 'DB-357', 'DB-437'))
            )
    )
```

I intentionally put some non-required brackets and indentation to make logic clear

Comment: Parenthesis where it's not required does not add any clarity